# Python- Saving files for each loop results

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to save files for each results from loop. 
For example, I wrote this code but it only saves one file which is named "prac10.csv" which contains final results ([20, 12, 69, 31, 88, 40, 18, 71, 93, 19]).

```
epoch=10
randomlist=[]
for i in range (epoch):
    a=randint(1,100)
    randomlist.append(a)
    print(randomlist)
    with open('prac'+str(epoch)+'.csv','w') as f:
        f.write(str(randomlist))
```

However, I want to save prac1.csv ~ prac10.csv with each loop results. 
prac1.csv : [20] 
prac2.csv : [20, 12] 
prac3.csv : [20, 12, 69] 
..... 
prac10.csv : [20, 12, 69, 31, 88, 40, 18, 71, 93, 19]

How can I modify my code?

Thank you

Comment: `with open('prac'+str(i)+'.csv','w')`  instead of `with open('prac'+str(epoch)+'.csv','w') `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a fixed variable file name `'prac'+str(epoch)+'.csv'` and you are overwriting your file on each iterate, so you need to use the iteration variable for your filename (`i` in your example):

```
from random import randint
epoch = 10
randomlist = []
for i in range(epoch):
    a = randint(1, 100)
    randomlist.append(a)
    print(randomlist)
    with open('prac'+str(i+1)+'.csv', 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(randomlist))
```

Comment: Really small modification. I got it now! Thank you so much